# How to mark a partition as unmountable?

Tags: filesystems, partition, gpt

I partitioned a MMC card into multiple partitions (in GPT format), and the very first partition is just padding space so that all other partitions are aligned to a optimal boundary.

Problem is, on boot Linux always tries to mount the first partition, which is almost guaranteed to fail, which 1) takes time, 2) if it should succeed, behavior is highly undefined.

Is there a flag I can set for the partition, or a config file that I can change, to prevent certain partitions of certain block devices from being mounted?

Comment: find and fix the fstab entry that's pointing to the first partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` for that mount point to make sure the init process will not mount it at boot.
You might have a line like this in `/etc/fstab` :

```
/dev/sda1  /mnt/your_partition  ntfs-3g  defaults,noauto  0 0
```